# Expiring an IE session using WatiN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, watin, session-cookies

I'm trying to write an acceptance test using WatiN which checks that a user is redirected to the login page if they navigate to a page after their session times out. I'm using WatiN's `IE` class for the browser, and trying the following:

```
// 1. Login

// 2. Do this:
Browser.ClearCookies();
Browser.ClearCache();

// 3. Navigate to a different page
```

But the user is always still logged in. Other info:

1. I'm running the test through the NUnit GUI running as an administrator
2. It's an ASP.NET MVC 3 site, using forms authentication and in-process session state
3. I'm using IE9.
4. If I manually clear all cookies in Chrome, the user is logged out
5. If I manually clear all cookies in IE the user stays logged in
6. If I call `Browser.Eval("alert(document.cookie)");` in IE it alerts an empty string

Given the above, I'm assuming this is a quirk with IE; any ideas how I can work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is due to the way IE deals with sessions and the deletion of authentication cookies; I found buried in [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/08/session-management-within-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx) that you can clear authentication information in IE by making WatiN execute the following JavaScript:

```
Browser.Eval(@"document.execCommand(""ClearAuthenticationCache"", false);");
```

This works! After this line executes the session is cleared and the next page navigation redirects to the login screen.

Comment: This does work, however, we have found that it can cause problems with subsequent Browser.Eval calls.  With our tests, the code: `Browser.Eval("1")` returns "1" as expected before the clear cache call but after the same Eval requests returns "[object Document]".  Just something to watch for.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Aaron! :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked around a bit and found this page: http://fwdnug.com/blogs/ddodgen/archive/2008/07/03/watin-api-clearcookies.aspx

Essentially says that WaTiN doesn't have the rights to delete cookies within IE, so the ClearCookies method doesn't work. I'd just set your auth cookie(s) (I think the default is ASP.NET_SessionId) to empty and see if that works.

Comment: That page states that "This test will fail on the line with ClearCookies", but that's not what I'm seeing. I'm running the test through the NUnit GUI running as an administrator, so maybe that gets around that? `document.cookie` is blank and manually clearing the cookies in the IE browser doesn't log me out anyway, so I'm not sure that's it.